# firefox transform scale makes the background disappear

Tags: html, css, firefox, transform, scale

I am trying to create a rather "complex" button (at least to my tastes), and I managed to make it work, until I tested it on firefox.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="got_a_background">
    <li class="blue_link_wrap">
        <div class="contact_link button_anim"></div>
        <a href="contact.html"> 
        <div class="pos">
            <div class="border_white"></div>
                <p class="blue_link_en">contact</p>
                <p class="blue_link_jp">お問い合せ</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xvkszyvm/1/

Joined a working fiddle, the result is a bit off mainly due to other files involved but the idea is there.

I need that button with a background and that additional border inside.
On hover, the background image should scale a bit to give a feedback on what you are doing. No scaling should apply to the text and the white border

The whole thing works perfectly on chrome and safari but not on Firefox.

EDIT: Apparently, the problem only occurs if there is a background on a parent div. Updated the fiddle.

Any ideas and Tips on why it is not working and how to bypass that?

Thanks

Comment: For your info: I cannot see any difference between Chrome 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Firefox 55.0.3 (32-bit) when I use your fiddle. Always describe the problem. "things don't work perfectly in Firefox" is not very descriptive.

Comment: Same here. And in IE11. But tell me, is the text on the button really supposed to be cut off when the screen is narrow?

Comment: the layout is no big deal, the only thing not working as intended is the scaling on that particular part. when used on Firefox. The background just plain disappear when scaling is applied for no apparent reason when I open my file on Firefox, last version. I know there shouldn't be any problem and that's exactly why I'm asking here.

Comment: Narrowed down the problem and it appears only if there is a background on a higher div. Updated the fiddle. not working on FF in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out I made a typo and got a minus sign on a z-index.
Talk about a stupid mistake.

Comment: The question does remain, why would that cause a difference between Firefox and Chrome?